# How to manage security context within multiple microservices

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

I am developing a system that relies on multiple microservices to provide analytics. I have one of the microservices managing authorization using OAuth2 (Resource Owner Password Credentials). My goal is to audit who created/updated a certain entity in an embedded column that look like this:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class AuditEmbeddable implements Serializable {

    @CreatedBy
    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 64, updatable = false)
    private String createdBy = "system";

    @CreatedDate
    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private Instant createdAt = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "modified_by", length = 64)
    private String modifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified_at")
    private Instant modifiedAt;
}
```

I am sure that token is always sent with the request because we using an ambassador gateway that authenticates every request. Right now I am using very kinky and wrong (in my opinion) method. I take the token attached to request using `@RequestHeader("Authentication")`, send the request to the authentication server to get user email (and roles) and pass as a parameter to the service, which in turns sets `created_by` or `updated_by` column. Is there a way to intercept and have some kind of context I can pull user info from automatically (with spring calling authentication service for me)?

Comment: Are you using JWT as an authentication token ?

Comment: No, its basic oauth. I guess it does not matter. I just want to get user's info from microservice that does not authenticate users. Right now I am using RestTemplate for that. Is there any easier way?

Comment: The reason I asked about JWT is because it a standard format which typically contains the identity and claims. Wherever this token is passed , the trusted services can verify and extract without calling the authorization server. This solves the main issue of identity propagation in microservices. With OAuth2 these days the prominent token type is JWT.

Comment: You are right, in this case, I would have to store decryption mechanism on each of the microservices though, what is in my opinion, bad practice. But it is definitely a possible solution, thanks for help!

Comment: Yes if you are using Spring security for OAuth2 support then it has got standard configurations (ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer , TokenStore etc.) to implement this.

Comment: You helped me a lot, I will do further reading. Would be nice if you answer, so I can give you the bounty and do less of sky poking.

Comment: If you have an authenticated user somewhere in the SpringSecurityChain being passed through you can always inject this by adding the `Principal` parameter to a RestController method. So you could access the authority which Spring already knows about. Was this your question? Not sure whether i got right what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be the propagation of identity and claims across micro services and of course how to design it in a best possible way. Right now you seem to be using OAuth2/OpenID. If you are using JWT as token then it is a standard self contained token which contains the user identity and claims.There are standard classes (ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter , TokenStore etc.) in Spring security which can be configured in each microservice where these JWT tokens can be extracted via a common logic across all microservices.If your token is something other than JWT then you will need to write custom logic to extract the user info and pass it further. Some good references for design can be seen [here](http://alexander.holbreich.org/jwt/) and [here](https://nordicapis.com/how-to-control-user-identity-within-microservices/).